# Flash - image used in movie footage

Tags: flash

I saw this site, http://en.tackfilm2.se/, whereby a user is asked to upload an image, which is then used throughout the movie footage.

Can anyone provide some direction / guidance in how this is implemented?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

I would have probably approached it using cue points in the flv, that would trigger events to display the image in a certain way... and then I would have realised that this was quite limiting.

Because of the way dynamic image moves within the video, and also that the time to load the video is shorter the second time around (eg. not some fancy pre-rendering), I'm currently thinking the video is loaded onto the timeline and then the image is animated ontop of it?

I would use a movieclip  with a green square as a place-holder image to do all the animations, and then stick the users image into that movieclip when they upload it.

... I would be interested to hear how other people would approach it.

This article here offers a few more tips/clues: http://ragingartists.com/2010/02/stopp-the-presses-anatomy-of-our-hero-interactive-campaign-the-best-viral-in-the-world-probably/